# SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor ON Tomcat 7.0.62

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, liferay, vaadin

I am getting the following error while deploying the project to liferay tomcat server 7.0.62.
I have already referred few solutions, but they were not helpful.
following are the links i referred to:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-does-not-start-due-to-error-deploying-configuration-descriptor-225116657.html

https://jefferyhaynes.net/2009/12/30/severe-error-deploying-configuration-descriptor/

the error log is as follows:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/my.portlet.group-portlet]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1912)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/external/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:56)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInitializer.onStartup(AtmosphereInitializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.external.org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 14 more

May 13, 2016 12:54:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor D:\projects\eagle\programs\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\conf\Catalina\localhost\my.portlet.group-portlet.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/my.portlet.group-portlet]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1912)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There must be some more error or stacktrace on your server

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have updated the full stacktrace. 
Regarding the slf4j.LoggerFactory, i have already added that to my dependencies. but still the problem persists.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.external.org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` requires somewhere the vaadin slf4j libraries. (Usually vaadin-slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar or similar)